# How to use model in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in javascript and React. I come from c#. So these two ideas are a lot of different. Now I would like to create a model and initialize it.eg in c#

```
public class User(){
 public string username{get;set;};
 public string email {get;set;};    
}
```

I can create a new instance of User in another file like =>

```
var user= new User();
```

And I can assign value like =>

```
user.username="User1";
user.email="user1@gmail.com";
```

**How can I do that kind of same logic in javascript?**

First I try to create new js file and do like that=>

```
export class User{
    constructor(username="",email=""){
        this.username=username;
        this.email=email;
    }
}

export default User;
```

I import like =>

```
 import {User} from '../../User';
```

And I use like =>

```
var testing = new User();
testing.username="user1";
```

but it says

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression 
>   no-unused-expressions

I just have the idea. I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Which line is that error on? Your code looks fine. Are you compiling this code to run in a browser or node or something?

Comment: I think Andy is correct. Importing {} when using default will give that error, since there's no object to extract the User from, since the User is the entire exported object, not something you have to destructure out of the export.

Comment: @JamesHay I am running in the browser and this error is happening in "testing.username="user1"".

Comment: It's a warning saying that you haven't used a declared variable, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Loran, how and where you are using `var testing = new User();`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the setter and getter if you want to set the variables after creating the object, not from constructor.

```js
    class User {
     constructor(name = "", email = "") {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
     }
    
     set username(name) {
      this.name = name;
     }
    
     get username() {
      return this.name
     }
    }
    
    var testing = new User();
    testing.username = "user1";
    console.log(testing.username)
    testing.username = "user2";
    console.log(testing.username)
```

Comment: Can u write a example?

Comment: @Loran added the executable script.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I try as u said but why I got undefined. Do u want to help me on Chat?

Answer (score 2):

First, `import {User} from '../../User';` should be `import User from '../../User';`. You don't need the curly braces if you're using export default.

(Edit: ravibagul91 is right. I didn't spot your named export. But I'll keep this comment in.)

Second, since your class accepts name and address as arguments to the constructor, just pass them in when you create the new instance:

```js
class User {
  constructor(username = "", email = "") {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

const user = new User('bob', 'bob@gmail.com');
console.log(user);
```

Comment: No need to replace `import {User} from '../../User';` with `import User from '../../User';`. OP exporting the `User` in both way, `named` as well as `default`. Anyway it will work.

Comment: @Andy , One more pls. If I don't accept the argument in the constructor , how it would be?

Comment: Got it, I will try like @AZ_ way.

Comment: @Loran, your code is working fine, the issue is something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {User} from '../../User'; // this is wrong
```

try like this

```
import User from '../../User'; // this is right
```

because you export the class as default, so you must remove the bracket.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
  
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  
  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  getEmail() {
    return this.email;
  }
  
  setEmail(email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
  
  present() {
    return "my name is " + this.name + " and my email is " + this.email;
  }
}

var user1 = new User("User1", "user1@gmail.com");
var user2 = new User();
user2.setName("User2");
user2.setEmail("user2@gmail.com");

console.log(user1.present());
console.log(user2.present());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `import {User} from '../../User';`? Can't you see OP exporting `User` as `named` and `default`?